# Ubuntu 12.4 Will Not update [Unmet Dependencies]

Tags: installation, package-management, dependencies

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libc6: Depends: libc-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.3) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 is installed
libc6-dev: Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.3 is installed
           Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 is installed
libc6:i386: Depends: libc-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 is installed
```

Any idea how to fix this? I am new to Ubuntu so lets take baby steps.

Answer (score 0):

Your `libc6` package is an older version than the rest, execute the following commands:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

After this, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` should run fine.